# Formula to resolve max size of subset of set of strings

Tags: assignment

A set made up by strings, each string contains m characters,
character is either ‘0’ or ‘1'. Now, what is the max size of the subset, which in the subset,
each string has at least n characters differ with others in the subset?

e.g.
m=9, n=5, the max subset size maybe 6: ['111111111', '110000110', '000110010', '000101101', '011001000', '101010001']

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. The question is not clear. Is it about counting zeros and ones? In your example, these string entries are `subsets` of what kind of set?